# Null object reference error for datefield

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have two datefields, One is for start date & another is for end date. I have to send the dates to get the values in between two dates from MySQL through PHP.

For first time i am getting the values correct then when i click again datefield i got the error like below for null object reference

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.controls::DateField/displayDropdown()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\DateField.as:2342]
at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12064]
at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12002]
```

& here is my code

```
<mx:HBox visible="{duration.selectedValue == 'date'}" horizontalGap="0" includeInLayout="duration.selectedValue == 'date'}"> 
    <mx:Label text="From" styleName="Helvet12Normal818181" paddingTop="2"/> 
    <mx:DateField id="startdate" yearNavigationEnabled="true" height="20" styleName="Helvet12Normal818181"  disabledRanges="{[ {rangeEnd: new Date(2011, 12, 31)} ]}" formatString="MM/DD/YYYY" color="0x000000" editable="true" selectedDate="{stDate}" change="useDate(event)" parseFunction="{null}"/>
    <mx:Spacer width="8"/>
    <mx:Label text="To" styleName="Helvet12Normal818181" paddingTop="2"/>   
    <mx:DateField id="enddate" yearNavigationEnabled="true" height="20" formatString="MM/DD/YYYY" styleName="Helvet12Normal818181"  color="0x000000" editable="true" selectedDate="{enDate}" parseFunction="{null}"/>
    <mx:Button click="update_clickHandler()"/>                                  
</mx:HBox>
```

Here is my Action script

```
protected function update_clickHandler():void
        {
             validateDates();
            if(validateDates())
            { 
                theOb = new Object();
                theOb["theTaskName"] = "GetSiteVisits";
                theOb["filterType"] =  "date";
                var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
                 df.formatString = "YYYY-MM-DD"; 


                var formattedStartDate:String=df.format(startdate.text);
                var formattedEndDate:String =df.format(enddate.text);

                theOb["start_date"]     = formattedStartDate;
                theOb["end_date"]       = formattedEndDate;  

                if(theModel.dashboardVO.activityID!=null)
                {
                    theOb["content_type"] = theModel.dashboardVO.activity_name;
                }
                else
                {
                    theOb["content_type"] = "watchvideo";
                }
                var theEvt:GetReportItemsEvent = new GetReportItemsEvent(theOb);
                theEvt.dispatch();
                theModel.tempAdminParams = theOb;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: From the stacktrace you're showing, it looks like you're using a beta version of Flex 4.5, which is a bit odd. Assuming you're using 4.5, the code at that line seems to say that the calendar dropdown of the DateField doesn't have a parent anymore. That's about all I can say without seeing the actual logic; the code you're showing is just a view.

Comment: Okay i will show the AS code also...

Comment: @RIAstar Any update from you ??

Comment: Hm, none of that code is affecting the DateFields; not directly anyway. Does something relevant happen in that `change` handler? I just noticed you're toggling `includeInLayout` on the parent of the DateFields. This might be related. As a test, try making the `HBox` always visible and included and see if the error still happens then.

Comment: Upgrade to the current release version and see if this still happens. I was having issues with the date controls in earlier versions. Most seems fixed now.

Comment: We are working on a huge project for this if i will upgrade then its not possible but any how i found an alternate with textinput & date chooser. Its working fine now. Thanks guys for your time & effort.

Comment: At last i reached to conclusion that its bug in flex till now which is they mentioned in release document till this date.